# Как обрезать так строчку?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, недавно возникла трудная задача для меня, и не знаю как её решить... Вот допустим у меня есть число:

```
1.45234235
```

Как мне сделать такую функцию чтобы **ПОСЛЕ** точки могло быть только две цифры? Т.е чтобы число получилось таким:

```
1.45
```

Пробовал в гугле поискать, но видимо не правильно запрос пишу. Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой.

Comment: чиста для поржать: а как в гугле запрос вводили? :) видимо не "округление" и не "форматирование числа"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Функция [round](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php)

Answer (score 5):

Неужели уже сказали про round() :-) Тогда так:

```
echo sprintf( '%.2f', 1.45234235 );
```

Answer (score 4):

я юзаю

> $sum = number_format($sum, 2, '.',
> '');

Comment: Неверно же.

Answer (score 2):

round(1.45234235, 2);

P.S. Ответа выше не разглядел...

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще извращенный способ:

`$n=4234.43943;
$n=((int)($n*100))*0.01;
echo $n;`

Comment: $str = str_split($str);
foreach.... ? не?

Comment: Зачем циклы лишние какие-то?) Тут же все предельно просто - урезать число до 2х цифр после точки. Конечно в любом случае идиотизм ибо есть стандартная ф-ция - round($n,PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);